# Template for Technical Manual / User's Guide using Memoir

Tags: memoir, templates, documentation, document-configuration

I am making a Technical Manual using the `memoir` Class, since I heard it is very customizable. Far now I've got this:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{microtype}

\hoffset = -20pt
\voffset = -20pt

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{huge}
\textbf{Apparatus User's Guide}
\end{huge}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, height=1\textwidth]{Images/Main/Plasma-Ball.jpg}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{normalsize}

\tableofcontents

\end{normalsize}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Main/Plasma-Globe.jpg}
  \caption{Plasma Globe}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}

\section{Components}

\textbf{Mechanics}

\lipsum

\textbf{Electronics}

\lipsum

\newpage

\section{Assembling}

\lipsum

\newpage

\section{Turn it on}

\lipsum

\newpage

\section{Calibration}

\lipsum

\newpage

\section{TroubleShooting}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But I am not very sure about how they look certain things and I don't know how to change them. For example the table of contents. All the sections start with `0.X` instead of `X`.

[image]

The other pages have in the upper right corner the word Contents. I think it is irrelevant placing that word in that place and I don't know how to remove it.

[image]

The Cover Page, I don't know if it is fine to let it the way it looks
[image]

I would appreciate any other suggestions for an User's Guide either using packages or configuring the `memoir` class. Thanks

---

Edition

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `\chapter{}` instead `\section{}`. Then you get correct numbers ...

Comment: But if I use chapter, now in the table of contents, the multiple dots don't appear

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think a user manual should have chapters. It looks strange for me. I uploaded a new photo of how it looks with Chapters, and it looks like a book, and is not. It is a Technical Manual

Comment: What manual? Also the table of contents should list itself as a content?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of your issues you need to change the code a little bit. Please note, that `memoir` does not support to change the line for a chapter in TOC (to add dotted line).

The code changings I marked with `<======` in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  8pt,
  a5paper,
  article % <===========================================================
]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{microtype}

\hoffset = -20pt
\voffset = -20pt

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{huge}
\textbf{Apparatus User's Guide}
\end{huge}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, height=1\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{normalsize}

\tableofcontents* % <===================================================

\end{normalsize}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction} % <==============================================

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Plasma Globe}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Components}

\textbf{Mechanics}

\lipsum

\textbf{Electronics}

\lipsum

\newpage

\chapter{Assembling}

\lipsum

\newpage

\chapter{Turn it on}

\lipsum

\newpage

\chapter{Calibration}

\lipsum

\newpage

\chapter{TroubleShooting}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It results then for example in the following TOC:

[image: TOC]

You can open the manual of `memoir` on your computer by typing in your console/terminal: `texdoc memoir`.

As you can see the pdf file is in A5 format (the german "Seiengröße" means page size in english):

[image]

Comment: How can I make a little bit larger the word Content?. And how can I make the body of the document larger too, because the page numbering appears too high. I uploaded a photo

Comment: I think partially solved it by changing \footskip = 50pt and \textheight = 400pt ... But now what got me worry is why a a5 paper appears on an a4 paper. Shouldn't appear in an a5 paper?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a5. See the last photo I uploaded

Answer (score 1):

I have some answers for you but you have asked too many questions in your comments. Here is something you may work with:

```
\documentclass[%
  % 8pt   % no 8pt option try 9pt
  9pt,
  a5paper,
  article, % chapters set as sections and so on
]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{2in}{*} % change the layout, see the manual
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage} % the title page

{\huge\bfseries{Apparatus User's Guide}}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, height=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\end{titlingpage}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep} % put dots in chapter ToC entries
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure} % for a non-float figure caption

\tableofcontents*
\listoffigures

\chapter{First major heading}
\section{A minor heading}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\figcaption{A duck} % figure caption but not in a float
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Second major heading}
\section{Minor heading}

(1) \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Please read the relevant portions of the manual (`> texdoc memoir`); I know it is large but it covers a lot of ground.

There is no `8pt` class option, the nearest is `9pt` which I have difficulty in reading.

Use the `article` class option to get the result looking like an `article`. The downside is that you have to use `\chapter` instead of `\section` for the main divisions. The upside is that if you later think you should have used the `report` or `book` class all you have to do is remove the `article` option.

I suggest you do not use the [H] option for floats, which turns them into fixed items (see [HEINEOUS](https://stackexchange.com/questions/469880) ). `memoir` has its own way of dealing with this.

If you are changing the layout then `memoir` provides a comprehensive means of doing this. You should never need to change the values of `\hoffset` and `\voffset` which are down in the nitty-gritty of TeX..

Comment: If there isn't a `8pt` class option. What size of the font was I using?

Comment: @Delfin The default is 10pt.